# How to find out which Control the Panel currently contains

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to find out which Control the Panel currently contains.

If I show my forms through a panel , then how can I find out which form the panel currently has ?

Comment: Good example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use Panel.findcontrol for more information you can check this link out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.findcontrol.aspx

Comment: I dont understand (unable to understand whats written in msdn), can you show me an example ?

Comment: hello tell me 1 thing you are working on which Forms Windows  or Web ?

Comment: Windows Forms , I forgot to mention it in the question

Comment: I already solved this problem using the example shown in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx). Thanks for your help and support :D